# How to escape all array elements from special characters while sending to mysql database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sql-injection

I am sending an array which has been passed from View to Controller(ajax-json).
In the controller, I am collecting all of them in array like this:

```
$to_update = array(
    'Name' =>$Name,
     'qualification' =>$qualification,
     'percentage' =>$percentage,
      );
```

And I will be sending this to Model for inserting in to database, and  the call is like

```
$result  = $this->MODEL_NAME->FUNC_NAME($to_update);
```

And in Model, they are insered like,

```
$this->db->insert('table_name', $to_update);
```

Now I have to make sure that SQL INJECTION will be handled properly and No harm takes place when any special charecters entered from user.
So I have to give ESCAPE functionality to the array. I have very huge arrays like above with hundreds of elements.

While saving it saves special charecter, but while fetching, there will be a problem and data will be lost. So Where I have to take care of escaping, and how
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of ActiveRecord's query-building methods `like ,where, group, order, insert, update and so on,` are safe against `SQL injection` AS LONG AS you do not pass them raw SQL strings.

CodeIgniter will recognize what type of data your variable is, and wrap it accordingly. That is, if it's a string, it will put ' and ' around the escaped value in the SQL, which is what you need to ensure that `users can't inject anything malicious.`

CodeIgniter is strip slashing the quotes and vulnerable scripts when using active records rather than running direct SQL queries.. So no wories for using Active records

Comment: Ok, But along with that, I also want to take as much as data posible from user. For example, if user enteres like  "HELLL'"0 THERE", I must be  able to save "HELLO THERE" and same should be fetched. But now entire thing is saved and only HELL' will be fetched while selecting. Is there any way.

Comment: before inserting them to the query like this :

`$var = $this->db->escape($var);`